# How to block output of a command run with via `run-with-idle-timer`?

Tags: echo-area, message, idle-timer

I use

```
(run-with-idle-timer 45 t 'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

to automatically save all org-mode buffers when I am idling for 45 seconds. What I don't like about this is that it prints "All org-mode buffers have been saved" to the minibuffer. How can I prevent this output from being shown?

Answer (score 1):

The O.P. could use advice to suppress messages for the function at issue, and there is an `inhibit-message` variable in recent versions of Emacs.  However, it is such a small function that can easily be duplicated with a new name by commenting out the two calls to `message`.

How did I come to this solution?  I opened Emacs 26.1 and typed:  `M-:` (aka `M-x eval-expression`), and then `(require 'org)` + `RET`, and then I typed:  `M-x find-function RET org-save-all-org-buffers RET` and took a peek see what makes it tick....

```lisp
(defun my-org-save-all-org-buffers ()
  "Save all Org buffers without user confirmation."
  (interactive)
  ;;; (message "Saving all Org buffers...")
  (save-some-buffers t (lambda () (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)))
  (when (featurep 'org-id) (org-id-locations-save))
  ;;; (message "Saving all Org buffers... done")
  )

(run-with-idle-timer 45 t 'my-org-save-all-org-buffers)
```